# MongoDB difference between Query and Write Operation Commands vs CRUD operations

Tags: mongodb

I stumbled upon the db.collection.find() [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-documents/) and the db.runCommand({find:..}); [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/find/#dbcmd.find) and it appears both do the same and Mongo Documentation does not do not tell when to use what.

I need to understand what is the difference, and the usages in both programming or shell environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `runCommand` version is the raw interface to the query functionality, and `db.collection.find` is the user-friendly helper method to access the same functionality.

You would always want to use `db.collection.find` (and the other helper methods) unless you're doing something advanced that's only available via the `runCommand` interface.

Comment: could you please cite an example which ones' not available in find() , that is available in runCommand() ?

Comment: @TheNeoNoirDeveloper One example is the `singleBatch` option that appears to only be available via `runCommand`.